# Durandaljs 2.0 routes are case sensitive

Tags: durandal

I am working on a durandal js 2.0 application. All works fine, except that the routes that I define are case-sensitive. I can also say that the starter kit for durandal 2.0 has the same problem.

consider this as my route.

```
router.map([
          { route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
        ]);
```

navigating to

```
 http://localhost/durandal#flickr
```

works without a problem, but navigating to

```
 http://localhost/durandal#Flickr does not.
```

Is there a way for the routes to be treated as case-insensitive.

Comment: Why would someone want case sensitive URLs? Is there anyway (configuration) to "inject" case insensitive route matching as the default behavior?

Comment: URIs are recommended case-sensitive per spec. Hostnames/domain names are not, schemes are not, but paths, querystrings, and fragment IDs are. When resolving server-based URLs, it's an implementation feature of IIS to not respect case in paths, whereas Apache enforces case sensitivity. In the case of client-side URI, the section you are looking at is a fragment ID, and indeed in your case it correlates to a Javascript module. As both Javascript variables and HTML DOM element ID attributes are case sensitive, a Durandal module route lives in an environment where case sensitivity is expected.

Answer (score 4):

How about setting up the route as an array?  That way you could cater for both eventualities.

```
router.map([
      { route: ['flickr', 'Flickr'], 
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', 
        title: 'flickr', 
        nav: true }
    ]);
```

If too many possible combinations to cater for with an array, the only option would be regular expression matching.

Rob Eisenberg suggests this solution for Durandal 1.x:

```
router.mapNav({ name: "details", url: new RegExp('details', "i") , hash:'#/details', moduleId:'viewmodels/details'});
```

*As a minimum, you must include the moduleId that that route maps to. If it's a navigation route and you are databinding to it's hash, then you need to manually specify the default hash as well. The reason is that we cannot autmatically derive the moduleId or the hash from a RegEx.*

This would translate to:

```
router.map([
      { route: new RegExp('flickr', "i"), 
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', 
        title: 'flickr', 
        nav: true }
    ]);
```

in your case.

Comment: to what extent? flickr was just a sample. I would have a whole lot of routes 'all-javascript-books' or 'All-JavaScript-Books' and the user may type in http://www.mywebsite.com#BOOKS/all-JAVASCRIPT-books... what are the permutations and combinations I will handle like this? Thank you for the suggestion though..

Comment: I understand your point. I don't have any situations where I would expect a user to type in a complex web URL such as you suggested but I can imagine it happening on shorter URLs.  This problem is not really Durandal's alone, it's a javascript thing. I've edited my answer to show a way of handling this via a regular expression. Maybe that will help?

Comment: It would be nice if it was the default behavior and not something I have to mention for every route that I define.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapUnknownRoutes and do a search for each route in lowercase against the default route list.  This would mean all your routes would be lowercased when they are created.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/

This would be done by using

```
router.mapUnknownRoutes(function (instruction) {
    Ko.arrayForEach(router.instructions, function(route) {
        if (route.route === instruction.fragment)
        // set route to this route
});
```

I am on my iPad so just giving you a suggestion not saying that works as is...

Another thing you may be able to do is set the regexp on the router.  Look at the API and it shows each instruction has a config property that contains a routing regular expression.  Try setting that to fix your route matching.